# How do I style certain Twitter page elements from a Chrome extension?

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension which interacts with Twitter to restyle certain elements of the page based on user preferences. I am able to restyle many elements on the page, but for some reason, the extension is not able to see or work with certain elements in the DOM.

Below is an excerpt from the HTML for the Twitter homepage a user sees once they sign in.

```
<div class="tcu-imageWrapper" style="opacity: 1; background-image: url(&quot;https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/960062309782585344/fGOYg2aA?format=jpg&amp;name=600x314&quot;); background-size: cover;" data-style="background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/960062309782585344/fGOYg2aA?format=jpg&amp;name=600x314); background-size: cover;">
    <img class="u-block" data-src="https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/960062309782585344/fGOYg2aA?format=jpg&amp;name=600x314" alt="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/card_img/960062309782585344/fGOYg2aA?format=jpg&amp;name=600x314">
</div>
```

I have a CSS file (overlay.css) included in my extension which adds a filter attribute to the style for tc-ImageWrapper class.  This injected attribute is never applied.  I don't see it applied when I inspect via the Chrome Developer Tools. I've tried applying it to the img as well as the tcu-imageWrapper div containing the image.  Neither work.

manifest.json (excerpt)

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
      "css": ["css/overlay.css"],
      "js": ["js/ready.js", "js/actions.js"]
    }
  ],
```

overlay.css (excerpt)

```
.tcu-imageWrapper > img {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

In contrast, I am able to see and manipulate the elements below (as well as almost any other element I try).

Another section of the HTML from the Twitter page:

```
<div class="AdaptiveMedia-photoContainer js-adaptive-photo " data-image-url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWDTA-EWkAEBQjk.jpg" data-element-context="platform_photo_card" style="background-color:rgba(53,64,63,1.0);" data-dominant-color="[53,64,63]">
  <img data-aria-label-part="" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DWDTA-EWkAEBQjk.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; top: -86px;">
</div>
```

overlay.css (another excerpt)

```
div.AdaptiveMedia-photoContainer > img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

The style above gets injected and applied correctly.

I have tried adding the style property manually through Chrome Dev Tools and it works.

I've copied the selector using Chrome Dev Tools and placing in my CSS file but it doesn't get applied. [See a screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8ZvO.png), and the [output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxQvf.png).

Any thoughts or insights into how I can style those tcu-imageWrapper images would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ensured that your CSS is being included **after** Twitter's CSS? If this is the case and your CSS selectors have the same specificity as those of Twitter's, yours will not be applied due to the cascade.

Comment: There is a 'run_at' attribute that can be added in the manifest.json which allows you to specify 'document_start', 'document_end', or 'document_idle', but the documentation says that it only applies to Javascript files in the content scripts.  I do believe the styles are getting applied subsequent to the Twitter CSS because I'm able to style most other elements successfully.

Comment: To be clear, the CSS selectors you have above work when applied through Dev Tools? That is, not directly to the element so it creates a `style` attribute but the actual CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  To clarify, when I add the filter property to the selector manually via Chrome Dev Tools, the page responds accordingly.  However, when I update overlay.css with the selector as reported by Chrome Dev Tools so the extension could apply it automatically, nothing happens.

Comment: I added screenshot references in the second to last paragraph in my post for reference.

Comment: I think it might be Twitter's [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP). In Dev Tools, click the _Network_ tab, then select _CSS_ a couple rows down to only show CSS files that were requested. Is your script included? If so, is the entry for it red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  Quoted tweets and retweets are loaded into iframes on the Twitter homepage.  All of the elements that I was previously unable to manipulate were getting loaded into numerous iframes.  Once I added the **"all_frames": true** property to my manifest.json, I began getting the expected output.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
    "css": ["css/overlay.css"],
    "js": ["js/ready.js", "js/actions.js"],
    "all_frames": true
  }
]
```

Thanks to those who tried to help.